# Eclipse plugin to know performance of a Java program

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, optimization, eclipse-plugin

> Preferably Eclipse Plugin

Is there any Eclipse plugin which can help me in looking at performance of a Java program?

> or (in case Eclipse plugin is not available)

If there isn't any Eclipse plugin, is there any other way?

**Update**

What about [mBProfiler](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/mbprofiler-0?mpc=true&mpc_state=)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't use TPTP, as it is [no longer maintained](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/project_info/devplans/EclipseTPTPProjectPlan2010.htm). If you're interested in profiling, have a look at [JVM Monitor](http://jvmmonitor.org/). It is very similar to (J)VisualVM, but with a better integration into Eclipse in my opinion. If you're more into micro benchmarking, [JBenchX](https://github.com/iquadrat/jbenchx) might be worth a look.

Comment: Thanks, also can you take a look at [mBProfiler](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/mbprofiler-0?mpc=true&mpc_state=), how is it?

Comment: I don't know about mBProfiler, never worked with it. Seems to be commercial. In a previous job, we've used [www.yourkit.com](YourKit) as a commercial profiler, and I was very happy with it, but mostly use JVM Monitor nowadays for my needs. mBProfiler seems to especially target embedded JVMs, not sure if you need that or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you can, use [jvisualvm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) in the Sun Java 6 JDK.

another tool is [visualvm](http://visualvm.java.net/api-quickstart.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jvisualvm to analyze the code and find bottlenecks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Eclipse Test and Performance Tools Platform (TPTP)](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/) to profile your java application